# Есть ли настоящее время у глагола отправить?

Tags: глаголы, спряжение

Как я понимаю, глагол **отправлять** имеет следующие формы:

> я отправлял - я отправляю - я буду отправлять,

тогда как глагол **отправить** как будто бы не имеет формы настоящего времени:

> я отправил - ??? - я отправлю.

Я выстроил их в соответствии с совершенным/несовершенным родом и не понимаю этой системы - можно ли считать совершенный род аналогом английского *perfect*'а, а его как будто бы прошедшее время - *present perfect*? Тогда как обстоит дело с *past perfect*? И есть ли примеры пар глаголов, у которых есть все шесть форм? Я придумал только глаголы вроде **пить/выпить/выпивать** с формами

> я пил - я пью - я буду пить,
>
> я выпил - ??? - я выпью,
>
> я выпивал - я выпиваю - я буду выпивать

соответственно, у которых совершенный вид всё равно не имеет одного из времен.

Comment: Не только Вы не понимаете всей грамматической системы :) Грамматика русского языка не порождающая грамматика, а описательная. Сколько грамматиков-людей, столько и грамматик. Вы можете, например, написать свою грамматику, в ней инфинитив глагола назвать именем процесса, и следовательно, инф.гл. будет безличн. существительным в вашей грамматике. *Пить вредно.* Здесь *пить* — подлежащее. Инф. можно описывать процесс в любой точке на оси времени, относительно точки времени о нём сказанного. *Я вчера пить бросил. Я решил пить сейчас. Завтра с утра буду пить.* Вуаля! Глагол в инф. у Вас отсутствует

Answer (score 5):

Глаголы совершенного вида не имеют настоящего времени.
Другими словами, когда мы хотим использовать настоящее время, мы всегда используем ближайший по значению глагол несовершенного вида

*я отправил - я отправляю - я отправлю.*

Answer (score 4):

Категория времени в русском языке существенно отличается от западноевропейских языков, так что не нужно искать аналогию там где её нет. В частности, *ничего* соответствующего ни давнопрошедшему, ни ближайшему прошедшему времени у русских глаголов нет.

Предложение "Я отправил письмо" может соответствовать как "I have sent the letter", так и "I had sent the letter", а иногда даже и "I sent the letter", потому что форма "отправил" говорит об однократном завершении действия, но не о порядке следования событий во времени. Если же нужно подчеркнуть этот самый порядок, то приходится использовать дополнительные слова: до того, ранее, перед тем и т.д. и т.п.

Аналоги Past/Present Perfect можно отыскать разве что в церковнославянском: ты любилъ еси = you have loved, ты любилъ бяше = you had loved и т.д.

Answer (score 3):

У совершенных глаголов просто нет настоящего времени. Можно сказать, что они обозначают бесконечно короткие события. Они не соответствуют виду perfect, скорее simple (не точно, но вид continous всегда, пожалуй, переводят как несовершенные глаголы, а совершенные глаголы - как вид simple).

Present perfect continous переводят как несовершенный вид прошлого (если событие окончено) времени, например:

> Вы смотрели фильм "Белая собака". - You have been watching the film "White Dog".

Я бы сказал, что вид simple обозначает короткие и очень долгие события, так что он соответствует несовершенному виду, если обозначает конечные короткие (Present Simple не может обозначать бесконечно коротких, потому что "теперь" бесконечно короткое, а по логике русского* языка две беск. короткие вещи не могут случиться в одно время) или очень долгие вещи (Present Simple как gnomic aspect или напр., когда можно поставить used to на место Past Simple).

<sub>* и польского, - я поляк</sub>